# PYthon ctypes 'TypeError' LP_LP_c_long instance instead of _ctypes.PyCPointerType

Tags: python, dll, arguments, ctypes

I try to use a dll which is written in C++. It has this function:

```
bool PMDllWrapperClass::GetDeviceList(DEVICE** pDeviceArray, int* nDeviceCount, LAN_DEVICE** pLanDeviceArray, int LanDeviceCount, int InterfaceTypeToSearch)
```

I tried:

```
cP = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64))
cIP = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32)
cLP = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32)
cDC = ctypes.c_int32()
cIS = ctypes.c_int32()


resultgetdev = PMDll.GetDeviceList(cP, cIP, cLP, cDC, cIS)
```

But it says:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_LP_c_long instance instead of _ctypes.PyCPointerType
```

I also tried using a double Pointer, but non worked for it. Can I solve it with ctypes or is that not possible?

Comment: What are the definitions of `DEVICE` and `LAN_DEVICE`?  You also need to pass *instances* of types not *types* and should declare `.argtypes` and `.restype`. `ctypes` also only understands **C** interfacing, so the `GetDeviceList` function must be `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is due to passing *types* instead of *instances*.  You should declare the argument types and return type so ctypes can double-check the values passed are correct.

This needs more information to be accurate, but the minimum you need is:

test.cpp

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

struct DEVICE;
struct LAN_DEVICE;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
bool GetDeviceList(DEVICE** pDeviceArray, int* nDeviceCount, LAN_DEVICE** pLanDeviceArray, int LanDeviceCount, int InterfaceTypeToSearch) {
    return true;
}
```

test.py:

```py
from ctypes import *

class DEVICE(Structure):
    _fields_ = () # members??

class LAN_DEVICE(Structure):
    _fields_ = () # members??

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.GetDeviceList.argtypes = POINTER(POINTER(DEVICE)), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(POINTER(LAN_DEVICE)), c_int, c_int
dll.GetDeviceList.restype = c_bool

device_list = POINTER(DEVICE)()     # create instances to pass by reference for output(?) parameters
landev_list = POINTER(LAN_DEVICE)()
dev_count = c_int()

lan_count = 5    # ??
search_type = 1  # ??

result = dll.GetDeviceList(byref(device_list),byref(dev_count),byref(landev_list),lan_count,search_type)
```